# Axios fazendo dois post com apenas uma requisição

Tags: node.js, react, axios

Boa tarde! Tudo bem com vocês?
Estou tentando fazer um cadastro de um usuário e de seu restaurante. Então eu primeiro faço o post dos dados do usuário e no .then me envio para a rota de cadastro do restaurante. Ele faz o cadastro do usuário e me envia para essa outra rota, mas nela me retorna um erro de cadastro do próprio usuário, e com isso não acaba fazendo o cadastro do restaurante

----------CODIGO DO POST DO USUARIO-----------------

```
Axios.post('http://localhost:4000/proprietario/cadastro', proprietario.dadosProprietario)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log('Proprietario deu bom')
        console.log(response);
        history.push('/Push/Restaurante');
        
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Erro no proprietario')
        console.log(error);
    })
```

----------------CODIGO DO POST DO RESTAURANTE----------------------

```
 Axios.post('http://localhost:4000/restaurante/cadastro', restaurante.dadosRestaurante)
        .then((response) =>{
            console.log('Restaurante deu boa')
            console.log(response);
            history.push('/Cadastro/Verificacao');
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('Erro no restaurante');
            console.log(error);
        })
```

------------------CODIGO CADASTRO PROPRIETARIO------------------------------

```
exports.cadastroProprietario = (req, res, next) =>{
mysql.getConnection((error, conn) => {
    if(error) {return res.status(500).send({error: error})};

    conn.query(
        'SELECT * FROM proprietario WHERE email = ?',
        [req.body.email],
        (error, results) => {
            if(error) {return res.status(500).send({error: error})}
            if(results.length > 0){
                res.status(409).send({
                    mensagem: 'Email ja cadastrado!'
                })
            }
            else{
                bcrypt.hash(req.body.senha, 10, (errBcrypt, hash) => {
                    if(errBcrypt){return res.status(500).send({error: errBcrypt})}

                    conn.query(
                        'INSERT INTO proprietario (nome, cnpj, email, senha, telefone) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)',
                        [req.body.nome, req.body.cnpj, req.body.email, hash, req.body.telefone],
                        (error, result) => {
                            conn.release();
                            if(error){return res.status(500).send({error: error})}

                            const response = {
                                mensagem: 'Proprietario cadastrado'
                            }
                            return res.status(201).send(response);
                        }

                    )
                })
            }
        }
    )
})
```

}

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Algo que você poderia fazer para ajudar a entender melhor o problema seria debugar o que ocorre neste endereço "/proprietario/cadastro". O erro 500 pode estar ocorrendo pelo conteúdo enviado pela requisição, deve estar faltando algo ou deve estar vazio, veja o que está chegando para esta rota neste caso.

Comment: Eu entendi o problema, mas o ideal seria colocar o código do lado do servidor. Para o seu caso seria o código que é executado ao chamar a rota: `/proprietario/cadastro`, do serviço que está rodando na porta `4000`. Assim podemos ajudar a descobrir o problema.

Comment: Adicionei o código!